# COM : convert 'const GUID*' to const wchar_t*

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com, mingw

I am porting some code from VS to mingw C++ . One of the statements in my code is

```
CFactoryTemplate g_Templates[1] = {
    {&CLSID_SystemClock, CSystemClock::CreateInstance}
};

int g_cTemplates = sizeof(g_Templates) / sizeof(g_Templates[0]);
```

I am getting the following error on the first statement

> error: cannot convert 'const GUID* {aka const _GUID*}' to 'const
>   WCHAR* {aka const wchar_t*}' in initialization

I am completely puzzled by this. I did a little investigation and noticed that
CFactoryTemplate is a class in `combase.h` . Also my project is UNICODE enabled if that matters. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: The m_Name member is first, it is a string.  Compare to [line 74](https://github.com/rdp/screen-capture-recorder-to-video-windows-free/blob/master/source_code/setup.cpp).

Comment: I dont get that - Could you explain where I am suppose to be looking for m_Name

Comment: Use `{L"SomeName", &CLSID_SystemClock, CSystemClock::CreateInstance}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code - you say you are porting is wrong, you need to provide different parameters to CFactoryTemplate, the compiler error proves that. Here you will find some sample code to init such array of instances of this class (you dont need to fill all fields):

```
// list of class ids and creator functions for class factory

CFactoryTemplate g_Templates[2]= 
  { { L"Gargle filter"         // CFactoryTemplate.m_name

  , &CLSID_Gargle            // CFactoryTemplate.m_ClsID 

  , CGargle::CreateInstance  // CFactoryTemplate.m_lpfnNew
  , NULL                     // CFactoryTemplate.m_lpfnInit
  , &sudGargle               // CFactoryTemplate.m_pAMovieSetup_Filter
                                   }
  , { L"Gargle filter property page"
  , &CLSID_GargProp
  , CGargleProperties::CreateInstance
 }
 };

int g_cTemplates = sizeof(g_Templates) / sizeof(g_Templates[0]);
```

from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa451506.aspx

also Hans Passant has given you other example